# Symfony2 & Doctrine2 get one result even if more exist inDB

Tags: doctrine-orm, limit, equivalent

Is there any equivalent for the following SQL code in Doctrine2?

```
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! The answer is

```
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->setFirstResult(0)

    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```